# How to add data to a Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

Am working on a Linked list in java. When i add data in it and print out the linked the result i get shows that the linked list is empty, but i just added some data to it below is my code.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class workPls {
    public LinkedList  List = new LinkedList();

public void addNode(PlsWork st){
    List.add(st);
}
public LinkedList getList(){
    return List;
} 
public void print(){
    System.out.println(List.size());
    System.out.println(List);
}
}

package linked;
import java.net.InetAddress;
public class Linked {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            PlsWork  ok = new PlsWork(inetAddress,"pc");
            workPls oks = new workPls();
            workPls okss = new workPls();
            oks.addNode(ok);
            oks.addNode(ok);
            oks.addNode(ok);
            okss.print();
        }
        catch (Exception error){
                error.printStackTrace();
            } 


    }

}
```

Comment: You have two `workPls` objects. And you add elements to one but call `print()` on another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are adding data to oks and calling print on okss, so you are getting an empty list.